# How to generate family tree for infinite generations in latex?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-trees, trees

Most of the templates i have found so far family tree is for finite generation, How can we code for infinite generation family tree, our family tree generation may be 4, 5, 6, 7 etc. Tnaking you in advance.

Comment: Maybe, you should take a look at [`genealogytree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree). You cannot really code *infinite* generations with it, but you only have TeXnical restrictions...

Comment: So you don't want to ever actually get the typeset result?